# $PlayOutMode:0 does not work?

Tags: jssor

I have set the "$PlayOutMode" to "0", which, as I understand from the docs, should prevent a caption playout animation.

However, the caption playout is still animated...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question!
I have just fixed the bug.
Please download the latest version.